# Use the graphdb SPARQL browser with any endpoint

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, graphdb

Maybe graphdb people won't like this, but I'd like to try their very nice browser with a couple of existing SPARQL endpoints, based on Virtuoso, Fuseki, who-knows-what (in the sense that they're not under my control, e.g. DBPedia).

I wonder if their product is available standalone, outside of their DB (which is really good anyway), to support this use case.

Alternatively, is there a similar browser around (I'm mainly interested in graphical representations, which are so Neo4j-like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphDB (RDF database) offers a highly customisable and generic interface similar to neo4j. With [Visual graphs](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/devhub/custom-graph-views.html), you can configure how the RDF graph is mapped to the visualization graph. Often the RDF graph is too fine-grained to be directly presented because it's designed to represent a generic domain with all its specifics as an ontology. A very common task rendering RDF data is to map a relation class (in RDF all N-ary relationships are modelled as a concept) as a direct link (predicate). Thus, any RDF data model can output multiple application-specific graphs.

You can use SPARQL 1.1 federation to query remote instances. When the query does not perform a remote join its execution time should be acceptable. To see a live demonstration over a very large repository check the [FactForge's public service demo](http://factforge.net/graphs-visualizations).

**Disclaimer**: I'm associated with the GraphDB product development.

Comment: Thanks @vassil_momtchev, that's very useful to know. My question is if this tool can be pointed at any SPARQL endpoint, or if it can only sit on top of a graphdb triple store. I'd like to use it with 3rd-party endpoints (eg, DBPedia), without having to load data into my graphdb instance. Maybe it can be done via SERVICE, but explicit support for this scenario would probably be better.

Comment: "SPARQL 1.1 federation" is how you point graphdb to "any SPARQL endpoint". In effect, you expose remote data as if it was in the repository where you ran the query.

Comment: @alexis that's impractical, I don't want to have to install graphdb just to use their browser, nor is it practical to use SERVICE all the time. BTW none of these approaches are fully federation (like eg, FedX), which isn't my interest here.

Comment: So you want not only to "point" the front end to another endpoint, you also want to install the front end without installing the complete product? Fine with me, good luck with it then.